# memory allocation in C while using pointers

Tags: c

Is it safe to run following program?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     char *p="hello";
     p="long string here";
     printf("%s",p);
     return 0;
 }
```

I ran this and saw that it was giving the correct output. But, will the following statement be safe?

```
p="long string here";
```

Will it not cause filling of unallocated space with these characters?

Comment: Are you purposely missing the trailing `"` in `p="lkjhlkh jh ...`?

Comment: Your program does not compile. Please check first that your program compiles.

Comment: simple test: `char *p = "foo"; int x = 42; p = "long ugly string"`, then check if `x` is still `42`.

Comment: @chux... oh sorry! i forgot to type " int the end of that string...

Comment: @DavidFrye  `char *` is mutable, you certainly meant a string literal is immutable.

Comment: @MarcB......... it is still giving 42 when i print x....... this may be due to allocation of address far away from that allocated for p

Comment: @ouah: Yes, I deleted my comment because I realized that what I wrote was idiotic :)

Comment: @DavidFyre........... mutablity is in java i think but not in c........ but i am not sure

Comment: Mutability/immutability is a thing in C, I was just confusing mutating a `char *` itself for mutating the contents of the `char *`. Bit of an amateur mistake, really, but I guess I'm still a bit of an amateur myself!

Comment: @user3437973 mutability is a CS concept, not something special to Java

Comment: If you use `const char *p = "hello";` the compiler can warn you when you try to change the pointed-to string (and allows you to change where `p` points to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program is safe. Both strings are constants. Your pointer both starts and ends up pointing to a constant string, it just ends up pointing to a different one. No blocks of memory are copied or moved; there's no need to allocate anything.

Simply changing what a pointer references does not copy the new contents over the old if that's the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your program is fine. The statement `p = "lkjh..."` does not change what `p` previously pointed to (the `hello`), but changes the pointer `p` to point to the new string. No memory overwriting takes place at all.

In particular, the following would still print `hello`:

```
char *p="hello";
char *q = p; // now q and p point to the same place in memory
p="lkjhlkh jh kjhlkj kljh kljh jkl hlkj hklj hkjl hkjl hkjl hkjl hklj hkjl hk";
// this will print "hello"
printf("%s",q);
```